# after user clicks allow, the browser is redirected to my server, without facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth

im implementing my own php facebook sdk. it works fine, but i'm still fighting with the oauth flow.
what i have now:
check if user has allowed my application and permissions
if not - show the dialog to login and accept permissions. this is all ok, but after clicking allow the browser is redirected to https://mydomain.com/?code=CODe...
i can then get the access token and everything but i would like that the facebook iframe stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the URL yourself as part of the auth process - if you want to send them to your app's canvas, use that as the URL.

If you're using the PHP SDK you're probably using the result of 'getLoginUrl()' - check how that works and choose another URL instead, bearing in mind the URL must be 'owned' by your app or it can't be used